# Getting null values when converting pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD object into Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

My dataset has one column called 'eventAction'.

It has values like 'conversion', 'purchase', 'check-out', etc.. I want to convert this column in such a way that it maps conversion to 1 and all other categories to 0.

I used lambda function in this way:

```
e1 = event1.rdd.map(lambda x: 1 if x.eventAction == 'conversion' else 0)
```

where event1 is the name of my spark dataframe.

When printing `e1` I get this:

```
print(e1.take(5))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So I think the lambda function worked properly. Now when I am converting to pyspark dataframe, I get null values as shown:

```
schema1 = StructType([StructField('conversion',IntegerType(),True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[e1],schema=schema1)
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

[image: 1]

It will be great if you can help me with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.createDataFrame` expects an RDD of `Row`, not an RDD of integers. You need to `map` the RDD to `Row` objects before converting to dataframe. Note that there is no need to add square brackets around `e1`.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

e1 = event1.rdd.map(lambda x: 1 if x.eventAction == 'conversion' else 0).map(lambda x: Row(x))
schema1 = StructType([StructField('conversion',IntegerType(),True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=e1,schema=schema1)
```

---

That said, what you're trying to do should be easily done with Spark SQL `when` function. There is no need to use RDD with a custom lambda function. e.g.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = events.select(F.when(F.col('eventAction') == 'conversion', 1).otherwise(0).alias('conversion'))
```

Comment: Hi @mck, I wanted to ask that if lets say the event1 dataframe has more than 1 column, then using these solutions will lead to loosing the other columns. Can you please suggest how can I just change the eventAction column and let others stay as it is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `withColumn`

Comment: Thanks @mck for a quick reply. I am actually new to Pyspark and not very good at it. So might ask silly questions. I tried the `withColumn` as:

`event1.withColumn('eventAction') = spark.createDataFrame(data=e1,schema=schema1)`

However, I am getting this error:
`SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Comment: please read the docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn . It should be used with a dataframe, e.g. in the second code snippet of my answer

Comment: Thanks @mck. 
Just need a little more help if possible: 

I tried this:
`event1.withColumn('eventAction', event1.select(F.when(F.col('eventAction') == 'conversion', 1).otherwise(0))).collect()`

but I am getting this error: `AssertionError: col should be Column`

It will be great if you can give me some guidance here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: no need to specify dataframe and select inside withColumn. Please read the docs carefully.